# Java: Download String HTTP GET

Tags: java, string, http, download

Good afternoon;
I need code that will download a small server string,
I have server that receives parameter and returns value via PHP

URL: http://127.0.0.1/page.php?var=a

The url can return with value "YES" or "NO"

I want to code variable and return the values

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line of hackey Java with no additional libraries.
Like so:

```
String out = new Scanner(new URL(...).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try (
  InputStream in = uri.openStream();
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
) {
  HttpURLConnection uriConn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
  int contentLength = uriConn.getHeaderFieldInt("Content-Length", -1);

  out.getChannel().transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(in),
                                outFile.length(),
                                contentLength);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use OkHttp
Don NOT forget to import first

> sample code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

More info: 
http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.apache.commons.http` has been always robust, light-weighted and user-friendly to me. By adding a header to `request` you'd be able to set `User-Agent` representing the client's OS and Browser information. Also, if server is sensitive to content-type, you could add another header for `Content-type` as, for example, `application/json`.
In case of using any authentication library such as `jwt`, token could be located here as well.

```
public class Client {

private static HttpClient CLIENT = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
private static final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1/page.php?var=a";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Client client = new Client();
    System.out.println(client.requestBuilder(URL));
}

private String requestBuilder(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    // Add headers: OS, Browser, Content-Type
    request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Linux");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = CLIENT.execute(request);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while (Objects.nonNull(line = reader.readLine()))
        result.append(line);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Hope that helps. Please don't hesitate to ping me if anything remained unclear.